# cocoapods: inherit! :search_paths doesn't import frameworks

Tags: cocoapods

I have a pod structure like this:

```
use_frameworks! // required for adding swift

target 'MainApp' do
        project 'MainApp.xcodeproj'
        platform :ios, '10.0'
        pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
        pod 'Harpy'
        pod 'UXCam'

        target 'Widget' do
            project 'MainApp.xcodeproj'
            platform :ios, '10.0'
            inherit! :search_paths
        end

        target 'Stickers' do
            project 'MainApp.xcodeproj'
            platform :ios, '10.0'
            inherit! :search_paths
        end
    end
```

I assume that `inherit! :search_paths` should give the Widget and Stickers access to the MainApp pods, however trying to import `TTTAttribuedLabel` or `Harpy` into the Widget or Stickers results in `file not found`. They are listed in the `framework search paths`, but not in the `header search paths` and I'm not sure if that's the reason why. How can you get access to the pod frameworks from the main app from within the extensions?

Comment: Have you tried looking at using an [Abstract Target](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#abstract_target)?

Comment: That may have gotten me closer, but leads to more errors. So, I'm not sure if this is the right route.